# Kohana - pdo error in auth module

Tags: pdo, kohana

I am writting an application in kohana framework and I have problem in user login method
I am using included auth, database and orm kohana modules. I noticed that are 3 queries executed to my sqlite database in login method:

```
SELECT user.* FROM users AS user WHERE username = 'dejwid' LIMIT 1  
SELECT role.* FROM roles AS role WHERE name = 'login' LIMIT 1
SELECT COUNT(*) AS records_found FROM WHERE user_id = '1' AND role_id IN ('1')
```

and unfortunately the last one is not well built query (I think) because the   TABLENAME  after    FROM is missing. This may be a problem in my models so I will paste my models code below:

APP_PATH/classes/model/user.php :

```
class Model_User extends ORM
{
    protected $_table_name = 'users';
    protected $_table_columns =  array('user_id','email','username','password','logins','last_login');
    protected $_primary_key = 'user_id';
    protected $_has_many = array('roles'=>array());

    public function unique_key($id = NULL){
        if(!empty($id) && is_string($id) && !ctype_digit($id)){
        return 'username';
        }
        return parent::unique_key($id);
    }
}
```

APP_PATH/classes/model/role.php :

```
class Model_Role extends ORM
{
    protected $_table_name = 'roles';
    protected $_table_columns = array('id','name','description');
    protected $_primary_key = 'id';
    protected $_belongs_to = array(
        'users'=>array(),
    );

    public function unique_key($id = NULL){
        if(!empty($id) && is_string($id) && !ctype_digit($id)){
            return 'name';
        }
        return parent::unique_key($id);
    }
}
```

If it would help I want to add that I tried to follow [this tutorial](http://jdstraughan.com/post/auth-module-for-kohana-31-using-orm-driver/).
My question is: why there is no `tablename` in last query?

Comment: "Why my code doesn't work?" considered to be a too localized question and thus not suitable for this site. In general, programmer expected to *debug* their code, to get the answer for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected $_has_many = array('roles'=>array('through' => 'roles_users'));
```

Or whatever table name instead of `roles_users`